# How to generate the UTF-8, output csv file through SSIS

Tags: ssis, utf, msbi

I have build a SSIS package to generate the CSV files from SQL Script code. But, requirements was output file should be UTF 8 encoding. I have tried with changing the encoding in "flat file destination" task. But, it did work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you set encoding in `Flat File Destination`, but you should set code page in `Flat File Connection Manager` to **65001 - UTF8**.

If you have issues after this, write me below in comments.

To set code page just select this from drop-down:

[image]